# Endlessh "Failed to start Endlessh SSH Tarpit"

Tags: 20.04, ssh

I have just learned about Endlessh package, I have installed following steps described in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKhKNUo6rJU

But when it comes to check if Endlessh is listenning port 22 nothing happens, Then, I checked the status to see if it's running but it doesn't, here the result I have :

```
xxxxxxxxx@localhost:~$ sudo systemctl status endlessh.service
● endlessh.service - Endlessh SSH Tarpit
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/endlessh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-01-03 13:14:16 CET; 2min 32s ago
       Docs: man:endlessh(1)
    Process: 186607 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/endlessh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 186607 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 03 13:13:46 localhost systemd[1]: endlessh.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 03 13:13:46 localhost systemd[1]: endlessh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 03 13:14:16 localhost systemd[1]: endlessh.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Jan 03 13:14:16 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped Endlessh SSH Tarpit.
Jan 03 13:14:16 localhost systemd[1]: endlessh.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jan 03 13:14:16 localhost systemd[1]: endlessh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 03 13:14:16 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start Endlessh SSH Tarpit.
Jan 03 13:15:59 localhost systemd[1]: endlessh.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jan 03 13:15:59 localhost systemd[1]: endlessh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 03 13:15:59 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start Endlessh SSH Tarpit.
```

while looking further answers to my issue, I found on github of skeeto/endlessh, this :
https://github.com/skeeto/endlessh/issues/39#issuecomment-727283671

I tried but I still get the same Failure status when restarting endlessh.
I forgot to mention that I create a config file in endlessh folder `/etc/endlessh/config`:

```
# The port on which to listen for new SSH connections.
Port 22

# The endless banner is sent one line at a time. This is the delay
# in milliseconds between individual lines.
Delay 10000

# The length of each line is randomized. This controls the maximum
# length of each line. Shorter lines may keep clients on for longer if
# they give up after a certain number of bytes.
MaxLineLength 32

# Maximum number of connections to accept at a time. Connections beyond
# these are not immediately rejected but will wait in the queue.
MaxClients 4096

# Set the detail level for the log.
# 0 = Quiet
# 1 = Standard, useful log messages
# 2 = Very noisy debugging information
LogLevel 0

# Set the family of the listening socket
# 0 = Use IPv4 Mapped IPv6 (Both v4 and v6, default)
# 4 = Use IPv4 only
# 6 = Use IPv6 only
BindFamily 0
```

Do you have any ideas what is wrong ? should I restart the server ?
Thank :)

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm well aware this isn't even pretend to being an answer: But isn't this an inherently bad idea? I would assume it's better to close port 22 altogether. With this, your server is still present online, and could be perceived as a target on other ports. It's best to be as invisible as possible, IMO.

Comment: Hi Arthur, well I still need to log on using SSH as it's VPS, but I admit changing port 22 to another one would prevent brute force bot and/or such, I'm already using fail2ban and forbide root login, I just want with endlessh prevent a dedicated attack

Comment: So your OpenSSH server is on a different port than 22? Because it should be in any case.

Comment: See how he is doing this in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-7CEklXcxY&ab_channel=SemperVideo  You should use the port 2222, so that you can use 22 internal. You have to configure your router so, that a attack on 22 will be transfered to 2222, where your tarpit can do his job.

Comment: Do you have a file `/etc/systemd/system/endlessssh.service`? If so, please add it's content to your question.

Answer (score 0):

- Locate your `endlessh.service` file (certainly in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/endlessh.service` otherwise use `find / -name endlessh.service`)
- Uncomment the line `AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE`
- Replace `InaccessiblePaths=/run /app` by `InaccessiblePaths=`
- Replace `PrivateUsers=true` by `PrivateUsers=false`
- Run `` setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' `which endlessh` ``
- Finally, restart your deamon `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart endlessh.service`

Normally, it should work.